# Experiencing TypeError (expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found) when saving a form instance to request.session

Tags: django

I'm running into trouble trying to save an instance of a form class in Django's `request.session` dictionary. I get `TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found`. The whole traceback being:

```
File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/user_sessions/middleware.py", line 46, in process_response
    request.session.save()
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/user_sessions/backends/db.py", line 73, in save
    session_data=self.encode(self._get_session(no_load=must_create)),
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 86, in encode
    pickled = pickle.dumps(session_dict, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

What's the scenario?

I'm testing form validation for image uploading. I'm disallowing file sizes beyond a certain limit, raising a validation error. The form instance bound to request.POST is saved in request.session, e.g.:

```
form = PhotoForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
request.session["photo_form"] = form
request.session.modified = True
```

and then I redirect to a different view to use the said form instance.

I've noticed all this works successfully most of the times, but for certain very, very big files where I'm supposed to raise a validation error, I instead get the error shown above. Not all validation errors result in this. For now, the pattern is that only extremely large files induce this. I can't make sense of that.

Can anyone shed light on what might be going on, and a possible fix? An illustrative answer would be great. My primary use case is to show validation errors on the form in case of erroneous input.

---

If I print the bound `form` before assigning it to request.session, here's how it looks for big files that fail validation:

```
<tr><td colspan="2"><ul class="errorlist"><li>File is beyond acceptable limit (10MB)</li></ul></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="browse_image_btn">Image:</label></th><td><input accept="image/*" id="browse_image_btn" name="image" style="width: 0.1px;height: 0.1px;opacity: 0;overflow: hidden;position: absolute;z-index: -1;" type="file" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_reply">Reply:</label></th><td><textarea autocomplete="off" class="cxl" cols="40" id="id_reply" name="reply" rows="3" style="width:99%;height:70px;border-radius:10px;border: 1px #CFD8DC solid; background-color:#FAFAFA;">
</textarea></td></tr>
```

If I manually try to pickle it using:

```
import pickle
request.session["photo_form"] = pickle.dumps(form)
```

I get `PicklingError: Can't pickle <built-in method write of file object at 0x7f024f1d9db0>: it's not found as __main__.write`

Comment: session can't hold an object. you might consider storing the object id in session. Then retrieve the object when it is required.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal: in that case I should get the error every time, and not intermittently, no?

Comment: not sure why are you not getting a syntax error there. There are two closing brackets.

Comment: Just a typo while writing out the ques.

Comment: you might consider dig into the error traceback more. Somewhere a None is coming out.

Comment: So do you have a pattern here? Does this happen only when you try out large files?

Comment: My guess, based on the above context, is that with very large files it exceeds the size limit for your session cookies and the data gets dropped. This would result in `request.session["photo_form"] = None` and explain the error. How are you doing the validation? Are the "very, very big files" less than the limit? Do you put the form into the session dictionary before validation?

Comment: @Asher: I'm actually assigning the form to `request.session` after validation. Primarily, it's job is to render validation errors when the page refreshes for the user (and say, they've tried to upload a huge file which exceeded the allowed limit). The 'very, very big files' are more than the allowed limit in my app (>10MB).

Comment: Does your validation take into consideration that the uploaded file might be none? I'm wondering if large files end up as None because they're too large, but they pass the validation because they don't have a size, then result in an error?

Comment: What does `PhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)` look like with a really large file?

Comment: @Asher: added that in the question. That does look like the error was correctly raised. I'm thinking if I can't solve the problem, I can at least circumvent it by extracting the validation error's text in the view, and passing it to the template. Something like `dict(form.errors)['__all__']`, although that still gives me the output with `<ul class="errorlist"><li>` attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use pickle to dump form object before putting it into session and load it using pickle from session.

```
import pickle
request.session["photo_form"] = pickle.dumps(form)
form = pickle.loads(request.session["photo_form"])
```

Sorry,You can just make simple type data into session。

or Your can put the template output of form object into session if this is enough for you。

for example: The content returned from as_p() method. But essentially in architecture design of Django， form is middle accesing object,it is not designed for storaged，the object to be storaged may be model object or input data. sorry, English is very poor.

Comment: Nice try, but that gives me a `PicklingError: Can't pickle <built-in method write of file object at 0x7f024f1d9db0>: it's not found as __main__.write
` when I try to do `pickle.dumps(form)`

Comment: Sorry,You can just  make simple type data into session。

Comment: Yea looks like I'll have to do exactly that, thanks anyway.

Comment: or Your can put the  template output of form object into session if this is enough for you。

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: for example: The content returned from  as_p()  method.
But essentially in architecture design of Django， form is middle accesing  object,it is not designed for storaged，the object to be storaged may be model object or input data. sorry, English is very poor.

Comment: Don't worry, I get your point. Would be nice to add all this information to the answer as well. I'll mark it correct.

Comment: I have added it